# When using pipe() in c, my file descriptors mysteriously get set to zero

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I am having problems using pipes in C.
The goal of the project is to fork into two children processes, B and C, that write to a pipe. Then the parent process reads from the pipe, without waiting for B and C to terminate. The forking has to be done using an exec system call. 
Here's my code

```
int main()
{  

    printf("Starting process A, PID: %d\n",getpid());
    int fd[2];//file descriptors we're using in pipe
    int i;//used for while loops

    //start the pipe    
    pipe(fd);


    //Spawn process B
    int childB=fork();


    if (!childB)
    {
        //Now we're in process B
        printf("Forked b says fd[0] is %d and fd[1] is %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);

        char *strArg[4];//string array for arguments

        //Set up the arguments we'll be using.
        strArg[0]= (char*) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        strArg[1]= (char*) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        strArg[2]= (char*) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
        strArg[4]=NULL;


        printf("After initiliazing strings b says fd[0] is %d and fd[1] is %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);
        sprintf(strArg[0], "%s", "PipeW1");
        int count=sprintf(strArg[1], "%d", fd[0]);
        count=sprintf(strArg[2], "%d", fd[1]);

        //We need to close the read end of the pipe before executing the writing code
        close(fd[0]);

        printf("About to execv B and fd[0] is %d and fd[1] is %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);

        //Do the execv call to switch to the different process.
        int errcheck=execv("PipeW1", strArg);
        if (errcheck==-1)
        {
            printf("Error opening PipeW1.\n");
        }


    }   

//Still in process A. Going to start process C
int childC=fork();

if (!childC)
{
    printf("Forked c says fd[0] is %d and fd[1] is %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);
    //We're in child C

    //Close the read end of pipe before doing any write code
    close(fd[0]);

    char *strArg[4];//string array for arguments

    //Set up the arguments we'll be using.
    strArg[0]= (char*) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    strArg[1]= (char*) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    strArg[2]= (char*) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    strArg[4]=NULL;

    //Put the name of the program into the appropriate argument
    sprintf(strArg[0], "%s", "PipeW2");
    int count=sprintf(strArg[1], "%d", fd[0]);
    count=sprintf(strArg[2], "%d", fd[1]);


    printf("About to execv C and fd[0] is %d and fd[1] is %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);


    int errCheck=execv("PipeW2", strArg);
    if (errCheck==-1)
    {
        printf("Error execv C\n");
    }
    printf("I should have already made C..problem!\n");

}


close(fd[1]);//close output, we only read here





//If I wait for B and C to terminate, the program works without incident.
// int retCode;
//wait(&retCode);
//wait(&retCode);

int count=1;
char buffer[110];
i=0;
while(count)//stop the loop when count=0
{
  count=      read(fd[0], buffer, 100);
  buffer[count]='\0';
  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  i++;
  if (i%50==0)
    {
        usleep(200000);
    }


}


close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
printf("DEBUG when ending A fd[0] is %d and fd[1] is %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);

printf("Exiting A\n");

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

The issue I'm having is that while executing the code my file descriptors fd[0] and fd[1] get changed from [3,4] to [0,0] respectively, despite me apparently not manipulating them. None of the tutorials I've come across explain this well.

The strange thing is that the code works if I wait for b and c to terminate.
Here is the output

- Starting process A, PID: 27457
- Forked b says fd[0] is 3 and fd[1] is 4
- Forked c says fd[0] is 3 and fd[1] is 4
- After initiliazing strings b says fd[0] is 0 and fd[1] is 0
- About to execv B and fd[0] is 0 and fd[1] is 0
- About to execv C and fd[0] is 0 and fd[1] is 0
- Now we're in process C, pid: 27459
- Starting B
- After importing strings to B, fd[0] is 0, and fd[1] is 0
- Exiting C
- B exiting
- After end of  B, fd[0] is 0, and fd[1] is 0
- DEBUG when ending A fd[0] is 3 and fd[1] is 4
- Exiting A

Thus the file descriptors are changed to equal zero sometime around when we are in the forks and manipulating the string arguments. Note that this seems to happen before either execv, so I think it's before the children's other code could affect anything.

Note that the integers themselves are zero before they are converted to strings with sprintf.

As far as I can tell, I am not directly manipulating the integers in the array anywhere. Thus, my best guess is that somehow the pipe is considered closed at one point, and the operating system sets all of the file descriptors to zero when that happens, but I'm having difficulty finding that point in detail.

I considered saving the elements of the fd[] file descriptor array as individual integers to avoid problems with pointers, but I suspect that they are stored in an array for a good reason.

I really appreciate any advice on the topic! Thank you!

Comment: Lets start with the simple stuff first: `strArg[4]=NULL;` invokes *undefined behavior*. The array `strArg` is declared as `char *strArg[4];`, which means it is only addressable from `[0]` thru `[3]`. While you're fixing that, try adding some parens to `main()`.

Comment: Parentheses fixed. 
I don't know how I missed the strArg[4] thing thank you.

Comment: Is this supposed to be redirecting stdout from the two launched processes back to the parent process A and the listening pipe? If so, you need some [`dup2()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) work yet to do. And there are several samples on this site if you do a little searching.

Comment: You're also closing `fd[1]` in the parent process *twice*.

Answer (score 2):

The line of code

```
strArg[4] = NULL;
```

Is sufficient to account for all the observed behaviour. The array is dimensioned to 4 and this overwrites off the end, and presumably hits the fd values.

Fix that and if it doesn't work, resubmit your question.

```
strArg[3] = NULL;
```

Comment: The clue is there. You did the tracing. It's just a matter of reading the code carefully backwards from the first error.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I may ask one more question:

So if this error were in my main process I would have caught it quickly due to a segmentation fault error I think. However, those errors seem to get repressed when they occur in the forked process. What would be the best way to make these errors more visible (or is it just debug statements)?

Comment: No, this error just wrote a zero into the next variable up the stack, which happened to be fd. It was never going to seg fault. Everyone has made these mistakes, but avoiding them requires quite different coding strategies, which are out of scope for this question.